# FileNotFoundException loading jar file even existing the file

Tags: java, file, jar

I have a application who load a jar file inside lib folder of a root folder, when I put this root folder on C:\ or in C:\somefolder works fine, but when I put inside of "Program Files (x86)" returned FileNotFoundException even  existing and running cmd on Admin mode.

```
    JarFile jf;
    Image img = null;
    compuservice = new FrmPrincipal();
    compuservice.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("Path of MainClass: " + Main.class.getResource("Main.class").getPath());
    System.out.println("Path Icon over MainClass: " + Main.class.getResource("Icon.png").toString());
    System.out.println("Path Icon over compuservice: " + compuservice.getClass().getResource("Icon.png").toString());
    System.out.println("Path Main.class: " + Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
    if(compuservice.getClass().getResource("Icon.png").toString().contains("jar")){
        jf = new JarFile(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
        Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jf.entries();
        while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
            JarEntry entrie = (JarEntry)entries.nextElement();
            if(entrie.getName().contains("Icon.png")){
                img = ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(jf.getInputStream(entrie)));
                break;
            }
        }
        if(img == null)
            img = ImageIO.read(compuservice.getClass().getResource("javax/swing/plaf/basic/icons/JavaCup16.png"));
        compuservice.setIconImage(img);         
    }
```

I get the System.out.println to debug the information and returning the right path.

Stacktrace with println from app:

Path of MainClass: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/CompuForte/compuservice/CompuService-0.0.13.4.3-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/compu/server/main/Main.class

Path Icon over MainClass: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/CompuForte/compuservice/CompuService-0.0.13.4.3-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/compu/server/main/Icon.png

Path Icon over compuservice: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/CompuForte/compuservice/CompuService-0.0.13.4.3-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/compu/server/main/Icon.png

Path Main.class: /C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/CompuForte/compuservice/CompuService-0.0.13.4.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files%20(x86)\CompuForte\compuservice\CompuService-0.0.13.4.3-SNAPSHOT.jar (O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.compu.server.main.Main.InitInstance(Main.java:37)
        at com.compu.server.main.Main.<init>(Main.java:24)
        at com.compu.server.main.Main.main(Main.java:102)
2015-10-01 10:11:16.384:INFO::AWT-EventQueue-0: Logging initialized @521ms
C:\Program%20Files%20(x86)\CompuForte\compuservice\lib
0 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR com.compu.ws.rest.app.AppWS  -
null
```

Comment: What path is it printing?  Show us the full stacktrace, and the precise pathname that you found println ...

Comment: Why perform all this elaborate inspection of the .jar file, when the entire operation could be accomplished with the single line `Image img = ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResource("Icon.png"));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see what the problem is.  Here is the path you are attempting your code is attempting to use:

C:\Program%20Files%20(x86)\CompuForte\compuservice\CompuService-0.0.13.4.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

Notice the `%20`?  That is a "percent encoded" space character.  It should be a real space character.

So where did the bogus percent encoding come from?

Here:

```
Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

The `getLocation()` call is returning a `URL`, and then you are calling `getPath()` to extract the path component of the URL.  The problem is that that method doesn't "decode" the encoding.

One way to deal with that is to use `URL.toURI()` to get a `URI` object, and then call `URI.getPath()`.  I think it would be better to use `new File(url.toURI())` ... which will give an exception<sup>1</sup> in the edge-case where the `CodeSource` for the class is not a file in the local filesystem.

---

<sup>1 - This is a GOOD THING.  The alternative would be that you attempted to interpret that path of (for example) an "http://..." URL as a file path.  Ooops!</sup>

Comment: thanks a lot, works fine. I just needed to add a class URI and pass decoded value to the function.